# Power BI Filter on MAX of a column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

My data has a column with the week number. I want a visual (graph in this case) to show the latest week which is the MAX of that value. The visual filter doesn't appear to let me put in the MAX of something, just the usual greater than, less than etc.

I can use a slicer to get the latest week but I want just one visual to show it. The rest of the report will be all weeks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the data of the latest week in your visual, you can add a calculated column like this:

```
OnlyLatestWeek = IF('Table1'[Weeknr] = MAX('Table1'[Weeknr]),Table1[Weeknr],BLANK())
```

Use this column in your visual in stead of the [Weeknr] column.

**EDIT**
In DirectQuery mode you can try using a measure in stead of a calculated column. Something like this:

```
OnlyLatestWK = 
VAR maxweek =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table1'[Week] ), ALL ( Table1 ) )
RETURN
    IF (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table1'[Week] ) = maxweek,
        SUM ( Table1[Amount] ), //use your own expression here
        BLANK ()
    )
```

Comment: Tried that and got this error: "Function 'MAX' is not allowed as part of calculated column DAX expressions on DirectQuery models."

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a limitation in DirectQuery mode. If possible you can add the calculated column in the source table.

Comment: Could I use a similar IF statement in the SQL query rather than alter the source table? Or Case When?

Comment: I did it: 

SELECT *, 
CASE Week 
WHEN (SELECT MAX(week) FROM Attendance) THEN Week
ELSE ''
END AS LatestWeek
FROM Attendance

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the 'Filters' function on the chart where data field is the key metric (e.g. sales), Filter type = 'Top N', Show items = 'Top' / '1', By value = time period variable.

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create one measure as MAX[TableName.Week] and drag it to your visual.

Comment: Done that, where do I drag it to? Everywhere I put it, it doesn't look right or have the desired effect.